# Should i use cluster connection in my redis client when using Azure Redis Cluster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, azure, redis

Azure docs are a little bit confusing, docs says:

> **Do I need to make any changes to my client application to use clustering?**
>
> - When clustering is enabled, only database 0 is available. If your client application uses multiple databases and it tries to read or write to a database other than 0, the following exception is thrown. Unhandled Exception: StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: ProtocolFailure on GET ---> StackExchange.Redis.RedisCommandException: Multiple databases are not supported on this server; cannot switch to database: 6
> - If you are using StackExchange.Redis, you must use 1.0.481 or later. **You connect to the cache using the same endpoints, ports, and keys that you use when connecting to a cache that does not have clustering enabled.** The only difference is that all reads and writes must be done to database 0.

And says:

> **Do all Redis clients support clustering?**
>
> - **Not all clients support Redis clustering! Please check the documentation for the library you are using, to verify you are using a library and version which support clustering.** StackExchange.Redis is one library that does support clustering, in its newer versions. For more information on other clients, see the Playing with the cluster section of the Redis cluster tutorial.
> - **The Redis clustering protocol requires each client to connect to each shard directly in clustering mode, and also defines new error responses such as 'MOVED' na 'CROSSSLOTS'.** (???????) Attempting to use a client that doesn't support clustering with a cluster mode cache can result in a lot of MOVED redirection exceptions, or just break your application, if you are doing cross-slot multi-key requests.

I'm using NodeJS [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis), but i don't know if i have to use cluster mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you referenced, you need a client that supports error responses for multi-key requests like [MGET](https://redis.io/commands/mget) in a clustered setup. These errors happen when keys stored in different slots are accessed via multi-key requests.

A redis client that supports clustering will also be able to redirect you to the right node, when accessing keys.

https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#playing-with-the-cluster

> The redis-cli cluster support is very basic so it always uses the fact
> that Redis Cluster nodes are able to redirect a client to the right
> node. A serious client is able to do better than that, and cache the
> map between hash slots and nodes addresses, to directly use the right
> connection to the right node. The map is refreshed only when something
> changed in the cluster configuration, for example after a failover or
> after the system administrator changed the cluster layout by adding or
> removing nodes.